# Paypal - Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl - How to turn on CURLOPT_VERBOSE

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, paypal

I'm currently working on a thin API wrapper to ease calling code implementation in order to take advantage of Paypal's vault feature, where you can store credit card info, without having to store it locally in our system. As part of the api wrapper, I am using Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl and keep running into a '401 Unauthorized' error, and not sure why.

To help with debugging I am trying to turn on verbosity via the Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl options but to no avail. If I do the same thing without the Zend layer, using vanialla php, I get the expected verbosity.

Anyone know how to turn on verbosity for Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl, or maybe why I am getting 401 Unauthorized responses?

My Api Wrapper:

```
public function createVaultItem(Hobis_Api_Payment_Gateway_Item_Vault $item)
{   
    $client = $this->getHttpClient();

    // Authorization:Bearer is not a standard http header, so we have to disable strict header checking
    $client->setConfig(array('strict' => false));

    //$client->setUri(self::URI_VAULT);

    $client->setUri('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card');

    /**
    $payload = array(
        'expire_month'  => $item->expireMonth,
        'expire_year'   => $item->expireYear,
        'first_name'    => $item->nameFirst,
        'last_name'     => $item->nameLast,
        'number'        => $item->number,
        'payer_id'      => $item->userId,
        'type'          => $item->type
    );
     * 
     */

    $payload = array(
        "expire_month"  => 11,
        "expire_year"   => 2018,
        "first_name"    => "Tipsy",
        "last_name"     => "McStagger",
        "number"        => 4816123412343720,
        "payer_id"      => 1,
        "type"          => "visa"
    );

    $client->getAdapter()->setConfig(array(
        "curloptions" => array(
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1
        )
    ));

    $client->setRawData(json_encode($payload), Hobis_Api_Http_Client::ENC_URLENCODED);

    $client->setHeaders(
        array(
            'Accept'                => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/json',
            'Authorization:Bearer'  => $this->getAccessToken()
        )
    );

    $response = $client->request(Hobis_Api_Http_Client::POST);

    var_dump($client->getLastRequest());

    var_dump($client->getLastResponse());
}
```

Response:

```
string(351) "POST /v1/vault/credit-card HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization:Bearer: 1234
Content-Length: 136

{"expire_month":11,"expire_year":2018,"first_name":"Tipsy","last_name":"McStagger","number":4816123412343720,"payer_id":1,"type":"visa"}"

class Zend_Http_Response#15 (5) {
    protected $version => string(3) "1.1"
    protected $code => int(401)
    protected $message => string(12) "Unauthorized"
    protected $headers =>
    array(9) {
        'Server' => string(17) "Apache-Coyote/1.1"
        'Proxy_server_info' => string(43) "host=slcsbjava1.slc.paypal.com;threadId=181"
        'Paypal-debug-id' => string(13) "c7eb668ff9035"
        'Content-type' => string(16) "application/json"
        'Content-length' => string(1) "0"
        'Dc' => string(30) "origin2-api.sandbox.paypal.com"
        'Date' => string(29) "Wed, 27 Nov 2013 00:57:33 GMT"
        'Connection' => string(5) "close"
        'Set-cookie' => string(41) "DC=origin2-api.sandbox.paypal.com; secure"
      }
      protected $body => string(0) ""
}
```

And the vanilla code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        sprintf('Authorization:Bearer 1234')
    )
);

$payload = array(
    "expire_month"  => 11,
    "expire_year"   => 2018,
    "first_name"    => "Tipsy",
    "last_name"     => "McStagger",
    "number"        => 4816123412343720,
    "payer_id"      => 1,
    "type"          => "visa"
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);

var_dump(sprintf('State: %s | Mask: %s', $response->state, $response->number));
```

And output:

```
* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.5.251.39... * connected
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (23.5.251.39) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com,OU=Partner Support,O="PayPal, Inc.",L=San Jose,ST=CALIFORNIA,C=US
*   start date: Aug 20 00:00:00 2013 GMT
*   expire date: Aug 21 23:59:59 2015 GMT
*   common name: api.sandbox.paypal.com
*   issuer: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O="VeriSign, Inc.",C=US
> POST /v1/vault/credit-card HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization:Bearer 1234
Content-Length: 136

< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbjava3.slc.paypal.com;threadId=444
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 362182266fe6c
< Content-Language: *
< CORRELATION-ID: 362182266fe6c
< SERVER_INFO: vaultplatformserv:v1.vault.credit-card&CalThreadId=89&TopLevelTxnStartTime=1429716e360&Host=slcsbvaultplatformserv502.slc.paypal.com&pid=1239
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 686
< DC: origin2-api.sandbox.paypal.com
< Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 01:05:29 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: DC=origin2-api.sandbox.paypal.com; secure
<
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
* Closing connection #0

string(34) "State: ok | Mask: xxxxxxxxxxxx3720"
```

Again, I am not sure why I am getting 401 Unauthorized, and try as I might, cannot get the first example (thin API wrapper) to display verbose output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, the issue seems to be with your authorization header. I think you want:

```
$client->setHeaders(
    array(
        'Accept'                => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/json',
        'Authorization'         => 'Bearer '.$this->getAccessToken()
    )
);
```

in order to match your vanilla PHP request.

Comment: Wow that was it. Apparently, zend was preparing the header which resulted in; `Authorization:Bearer: 1234`, which is malformed. Doing as you suggested, it worked as expected. Thanks for the catch. As far as the verbosity goes, I was trying to get an apples to apples comparison between the vanilla and thin wrapper calls to see if there was something else happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Going to accept this, even though it answered only part of the OP. Still not sure if possible to have Zend api output data based on CURLOPT_VERBOSE flag.